# Bevel not working sometimes

Tags: bevel

Im new in Blender and im watching tutorial. But here is a problem. Part of my objects works like it should with Bevel Tool. BUT sometimes just not. I don't know what im doing wrong or what should i change. This is how it looks when im Beveling those edges and its alright... [image]

But right here im trying to Bevel edges below previous. And when im trying to Bevel them they like... Bevel in 2D? I don't know how to call it.
[image: Not working]

I have no idea what im doing wrong, i did research about it but didn't found anything helpful.

Comment: Hmm. If this is truly one mesh ie what it looks like, this shouldn’t be happening. Try selecting all, and then Merge -> By distance.

Answer (score 0):

you have many edges in the same place,

[image]

you can disolve these by selecting all mesh and press "M" key and select "By Distance"

[image]

Comment: Wow i don't know how this works and what i did wrong in my "project" but it worked. I mean i tried before delete one of those edges, vertexes and after deleting there was nothing, soo i thought it is not a problem here. Thank you very much, sometimes simple ask takes less time than hours of searching! Thanks again, should i delete this post?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to delete this post. Maybe someone in the future will have this same problem.